# I would like assistance updating a lookup field on the account when I select values from a picklist I got this code but it does not work

Tags: apex

My code is below:

```
Trigger Updateacc on account (before insert, before update) 
{
    for (account acc:Trigger.new){
        if (acc.recordtypeid!='012i0000000tXlc')                
        {acc.Account_self_lookup__c =  acc.Picklist_for_trigger__c;

        }
    }
```

ANy suggestions on what I am doing here?

Comment: What values do you have in the picklist?

Answer (score -1):

Does this need to be bulkified?  If not, this could be a Process Builder solution for you.  Just run it off if the record type is true on an account and have the lookup populated by the picklist.  If you'll be doing mass data loads often though, this would cause some extra work on the data management side to work around though.